# There are 3 tables in 1word (.docx), In want to Write each table from .docx to Excel each sheet (.xlsx) using openpyxl eg table1 to sheet1, t2 to s2

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have 3 or more tables say Table1, Table2, Table3 in one word document(.docx), I want to copy each table to separate sheet in excel(.xlsx) file using openpyxl or xlsxwriter. Example table 1 to sheet1, table2 to sheet2, table3 to sheet 3 of same .xlsx file.

```
from docx.api import Document
import xlsxwriter

document = Document(r'C:/doc/document_with_tables.docx')
tables = document.tables


wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:/res/result.xlsx')
Sheet1 = wb.add_worksheet("Sample")
index_row = 0

print(len(tables))

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for x, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            Sheet1.write(index_row, x, cell.text)
        index_row += 1
wb.close()
```

I am copying the multiple tables from (.docx) file to Sheet1 one in excel file using the above code, Now I'm trying to copy each table from (.docx) to sperate sheet in excel file. Can some one help with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What exactly is your question?  What is the code that you need help with?   SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: @ewong, I want a python code for my above question, I am able to copy tables for word(.docx) to single sheet in .xlsx file using xlsxwriter. But not sure how to copy each table to separate sheet in .xlsx. Thanks for your reply on my post.

Comment: Please include that code in the post and not in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new sheet each time you write a table from the doc in the for loop.

1. New table
2. New Sheet
3. Reset the index_row here so that each table starts at A1
4. Write table

see changes to your code;

```
...
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:/res/result.xlsx')
# Sheet1 = wb.add_worksheet("Sample")
# index_row = 0

print(len(tables))

for table in document.tables:
    ws_new = wb.add_worksheet()
    index_row = 0
    for row in table.rows:
        for x, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            ws_new.write(index_row, x, cell.text)
        index_row += 1

wb.close()
```